# Conflict in if statement using !in_category() && !has_post_format()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am quite new to WordPress and PHP. I have a problem with posting specific posts on the front page (but I don't use static page option, using the index.php).

I have 2 categories (blog and tips) and currently, I am using 2 formats (standard and aside). Blogs are only assigned to standard and tips are only for the aside format. I want to display them in loop with posts which are in the Blog category & standard format.

```
<?php if ( have_posts()) : ?>

  <div id="ob-grid" class="grid-layout">
    <?php if( !in_category('Blog') && !has_post_format()) : ?>
        <?php $i=1; while (have_posts() && $i<5 ) : the_post();?>
            <?php   get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );?>
        <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>

      <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
        <?php   get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
  <?php do_action( 'E2R_posts_navigation' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>
  <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The problem is that the `!in_category('Blog') && !has_post_format()` are excluding each other and getting into else condition (displays all posts) and I can't find the problem (before I used instead of 'Blog', 'Tips' but it did not work either). When I put the condition for !has_post_format() in the while loop, then it filters correctly but the numbering then does not work properly.

The post formats are defined as:

```
add_theme_support(
  'post-formats', array(
    'aside',
    'image',
    'video',
    'quote',
    'link',
  )
);
```

Comment: To clarify: are you using any plugins?

Comment: I did install several of them, but I am not using them at the moment

Comment: I tried, no change :/

Comment: You might also want to try searcing [Wordpress Stackexchange](https://stackexchange.com/filters/342) if StackOverflow doesn't help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution for this problem by position change of the $i iteration. It looks like:

```
           <div id="ob-grid" class="grid-layout">
              <?php if( !is_category('Blog')) : ?>
                  <?php $i=1; while (have_posts() && $i<5 ) : the_post();?>
                    <?php if( !has_post_format()) : ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );?>
                        <?php $i++ ;?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                  <?php endwhile;?>
               <?php endif;?>
```

I got back to the point: ok, here it was displaying correctly but the number of the post was incorrect (the number of standard-blog posts minus number of aside-tip posts). so I said increment $i only if the post has no format -> !has_post_format() -> is standard. The syntax and functionality of this WordPress functions is weird. but it works for me.